# Finding classes implementing an interface, using reflection, and instantiating them in F#

Tags: f#

I am trying to achieve the following:

I have an interface, called *IBotCommand* and a few classes that implement it. I want to find all these classes, through reflection, instantiate an instance of each and put the result in a dictionary.

the interface is the following:

```
type IBotCommands =

    abstract member Name: unit -> string
    abstract member Description: unit -> string
    abstract member Help: unit -> string
    abstract member Execute: MessageEventArgs -> string[] -> string
```

and the code:

```
let t = typeof<IBotCommands>
t.Assembly.GetTypes()
 |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.IsSubclassOf(t))
 |> Seq.iter (fun x ->
     (
         let i = Activator.CreateInstance(x) :> IBotCommands
         botCommands.[i.Name] <- i
     )
 )
```

the issue I have is with the CreateInstance line. CreateInstance returns an *obj* type that can't be cast to IBotCommands.

I have the same in C# and it works properly but the C# version is using dynamics:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Type> FindClassSubclassOfType<T>()
    {
        var a = typeof(T)
                .Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)))
                .Select(t => t);

        return a.ToList();
    }

    var types = ReflectionHelper.FindClassSubclassOfType<BotCommand>();
    foreach (var t in types)
    {
        dynamic c = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        BotCommands[c.Name] = c;
    }
```

how can I get this behavior to work in F#?

can you cast an object to an interface in F#? it's my first time using interfaces in F#

Comment: F# follows .NET class and interface behavior.. so yes, any object which is a subtype of X (direct or indirect) can be cast to X.

Comment: I'm not at the computer anymore, but I just had an idea: can I unbox the obj to its original type then cast it to the interface?

Comment: See “downcast”, noting a different operator is used - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/casting-and-conversions#casting-object-types “ Casting *down a hierarchy*, from a base object reference to a derived object reference [such as object -> X], succeeds only *if the object actually **is an instance of** the correct destination* (derived) type or a type derived from the destination type.”

Comment: While you can do this (use reflection, make a dictionary of types), it is almost certainly a terrible idea because you are not writing a compiler. You will not get the benefits of F# (namely the type system) if you use these parts of the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In F#, there is a difference between upcast `a :> T` and downacst `a :?> T`.

- Upcast is used when the compiler statically knows that `a` implements an interface `T`. This is useful if you have a value of a concrete class and want to get a value that has a type of an interface.
- Downcast is used when the compiler does not statically know whether `a` implements an interface. In other words, this means that the cast can fail.

In your case, you need a downcast, because the compiler does not know whether `obj` implements `IBotInterface`. All you need to do is to add `?`:

```
let i = Activator.CreateInstance(x) :?> IBotCommands
botCommands.[i.Name] <- i
```

Comment: To the OP: a downcast is a failure to work within the type system, so a good practice would be to write an apology comment every time you use one.

Comment: I could see situations where a blame comment would be appropriate as well ;)